# Mongo Replica Endpoint

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have some questions about the mongo replica
[mongo replica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlyxn.png)

If I make 1 primary and 2 secondary MongoDB for replication. So I have 3 endpoints to 3 different DB and my apps can only write on primary DB. what if suddenly my primary shutdown and secondary DB take over the primary. Then how to automatically change the endpoint in my apps? should I use mongos (mongo routes)? but it needs sharding if I remember correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In a proper connection string you will provide all three RS members, e.g.

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl
```

The client will detect the PRIMARY and will use it. I guess, most drivers will re-connect automatically if the PRIMARY node changes.

Most drivers will detect the PRIMARY automatically if you provide the ReplicaSet name, i.e.

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl
```

would connect to the PRIMARY even if it is not mongodb0.example.com. However, if mongodb0.example.com does not run, then you don't connect at all. So, it is beneficial to provide all ReplicaSet members in the connection string.

See [Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)

mongos is needed only to connect to a [Sharded Cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-components/).

Answer (score 0):

All nodes in a replica set work together to have identical data. Secondary nodes may lag behind the primary, but you don't get "3 different DB". There is only one database of which copies exist on each node.

All MongoDB drivers know to monitor replica set members and discover which is the primary one automatically. You need to configure some drivers to do so by providing the replica set name, others do it automatically by default when they connect to a replica set node. Look up "connecting to replica set" in your driver documentation.